# Shipping Not Calculating for Bundled Product

Tags: shipping, bundled-product

I have created a new bundle product and everyone looks great until I put it into the shopping cart.  Once it's there I cannot get a quote or calculate the shipping costs.  I have FedEx configured and working correctly for individual/simple products. Unfortunately it does not give me any error messages.  I'm looking for any suggestions of how I can troubleshoot this.  Thanks!